# Branches created using BranchPythonOperator do not merge?

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am using BranchPythonOperator to make branches in airflow. My use case is I need to make two branches from mainstream. Branch A (which has few tasks) will be followed when somefile.csv is present otherwise Branch B(which has no task) to follow. At last both branches should be merged to make a mainstream again. 
Now I am able to follow either Branch A or Branch B but the issue is if I follow Branch B final mainstream tasks executed and if I follow Branch A final mainstream tasks are being skipped.

```
MainstreamTaskA.setDownStream(MainstreamTaskB)
MainstreamTaskB.setDownStream(BranchATaskA)
BranchATaskA.setDownStream(MainstreamTaskC)
MainstreamTaskB.setDownStream(MainstreamTaskC)
```

I have set trigger rule as "all_done" in MainstreamTaskB and MainstreamTaskC.

Can somebody guide me through this?

Comment: Please share your process code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see the other branch in your dependencies. The only branch is `BranchATaskA`.
But based on what you have mentioned you should have the following task dependencies and have two branch tasks `BranchATaskA` and `BranchATaskB`.

```
MainstreamTaskA >> MainstreamTaskB
MainstreamTaskB >> BranchATaskA >> MainstreamTaskC
MainstreamTaskB >> BranchATaskB >> MainstreamTaskC
```

You should have trigger rule as `all_done` on `MainstreamTaskC`.

Comment: I understand your doubt. But there are no tasks in BranchB. It is like following a mainstream only but at one task based on certain condition I need to include 1 or more tasks in between MainstreamTaskA and MainstreamTaskC.

Comment: You can use DummyOperator for `BranchB`. There can't be a no-task in the 2nd branch.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. I was also searching and got this, https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html and search for this string "If you want to skip some tasks, keep in mind that you can’t have an empty path, if so make a dummy task". I added this link here just for reference.